# DirectoryStream is empty, even though there is a file in the directory

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a problem with the [DirectoryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html). I currently try to build a LogViewer for my application, which should iterate over all the Files in a directory and add them to a Grid.

[image: This is the directory.]

For testing purposes it currently holds only one file.

And here's the Code:

```
final Path logDirPath = Paths.get(this.logDir);
    if (logDirPath.toFile().isDirectory()) {
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(logDirPath, "*.log")) {
            for (Path p : directoryStream) {
                logFiles.add(new LogFile(p.toFile()));
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            this.logger.error("Could not read files in directory {}", this.logDir, e);
        }
    }
```

The value for `logDir` is `logs/activity`.

I tried debugging it, but it just skips over the line `logFiles.add(new LogFile(p.toFile()));`, so it seems like the directory has to be empty, but I know it's not.

So, can anyone spot the problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

I get the `logDir` via

```
@Value("${logging.directory}")
private String logDir;
```

from the `application.properties` file, which looks like

```
logging.directory=logs/activity
logging.file=${logging.directory}/activity.log
```

However, I don't think it has anything to do with that, as I already tried replacing `logDir` by simply hardcoding `logs/activity`.

Comment: How certain are you that `logDir` is pointing to the correct directory? Could there be an issue with the relative path?

Comment: I'm sure that `logDir` is pointing to the right directory. I also tried to replace it with `logs/activity`, but that does not make any difference.

Comment: Does it enter the if (..isDirectory())?

Comment: Yes it does, it goes until the for-loop.

Comment: What happens if you try "logDirPath.toFile().List()"?

Comment: Print "logDirPath.toFile().getAbsolutePath()" as well. You never know

Comment: I already tried the “logDirPath.toFile().getAbsolutePath(). Gave output as expected.
I'll try the other one when I'm back on work on tuesday.

Comment: So, `logDirPath.toFile().list()` actually returns my `activity.log` File. So that does not seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved: I was just not adding the logFiles List to the Grid.

What made me think that the `DirectoryStream` being empty was the mistake, was that the debugger jumped over the for-loop. I guess that's just how the eclipse debugger handles it.

I have worked with IntelliJ before, and I'm pretty sure that's not how their debugger handles it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a file visitor. This is safer anyway, as all resources are guaranteed to be freed when visit ends. Also, it gives about every entry point necessary to customize how you should iterate your file system.

```
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("logs/activity"), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (file.endsWith(".log")) {
            // Handle log file.
        }

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        // Handle exception
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        // CONTINUE if you want recursive behaviour, SKIP_SUBTREE if not.
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```